# Using TC Electronic Ditto Looper and TC Helicon Ditto Mic Looper together?

Tags: guitar, effects-pedal, looping

Is it possible to control instrument and mic looper together? I would like to loop/stop both loopers on one button. Can I do that with ABY switch pedal or some other configuration?